# What type of cast is appropriate here?

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have this abstract class template called `BaseNode` defined like this

```
template<class T>
class BaseNode
{
public:
    T* addChildNode(const char *name);
    void deleteChildNode(const char *name);
    void deleteAllChildNodes();

    T* findFirstNode(const char *name);
    T* getChildNode(const char *name);
    T* getChildNode(unsigned int index);

    void setName(const char *name);
    void setTranformation(const glm::mat4 &transformation);

    unsigned int getNumChildren() const { return _children.size(); }
    const char *name() const { return _name.c_str(); }
    T* parent() const { return _parent; }
    const glm::mat4& transformation() const { return _transformation; }
    const glm::mat4& toRootTransformation() const { return _toRoot; }

protected:
    BaseNode(const char *nodeName, T *parent);
    virtual ~BaseNode();

    std::string _name;

    glm::mat4 _transformation;
    glm::mat4 _toRoot;

    T *_parent;
    std::vector<T*> _children;
};
```

The functionality of this class is that I can create my own type of "node classes" and then they will inherit all the scene graph methods of this class template. (e.g `class MyNode : public BaseNode<MyNode> {...};`

The `addChildNode(const char *name)` function inserts a `new T(name, this)` to the children vector, when `this` is supposed to be the child's parent. The compiler throws a casting error and suggests that I use some kind of cast for this. I'm using `dynamic_cast` at the moment but this really bothers me as I think it's useless.

My question is if it's safe to use reinterpret_cast (which is basically just like a C-cast ..?) in this case like so: `_children.push_back(new T(name, reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)));` Because IMO dynamic_cast will never fail.

Comment: `static_cast` is the closest to C-cast.

Comment: @TartanLlama Take a look at MyNode example.

Comment: Don't reinterpret cast from parent to child pointer or vice versa. This is UB, and it's guaranteed to fail with some base classes if you have multiple inheritance. Use static_cast instead. Actually prefer dynamic_cast unless you *know* it will incur significant performance penalty *in your program*. Only use reinterpret_cast to cast your pointers to (possibly cv-qualified) `void*` or `char*` and back.

Comment: @n.m I would use a dynamic_cast only when there is doubt about the run time type of the object being a compatible type for static_cast.  C++ programs are inherently exposed to programmer error almost everywhere.  Coding inefficiently (even where efficiency isn't known to matter) to close off one tiny source of programmer error, is foolish.

Comment: @JSF What's foolish is a production system that hits UB, goes haywire and corrupts customer data instead of detecting and reporting a logical error in a complex, not formally verivied system.

Comment: @JSF: I disagree with that.  A dynamic_cast only costs 25% more than the equivalent static_cast.  Unless you're dereferencing pointers billions of times, you won't even notice the performance difference.  And if that saves a developer a day of debugging time when UB pops up in production code, I think the correct trade-off is clear.

Comment: Where did you get that 25% nonsense?  Have you ever profiled it or looked at the generated asm code.  Maybe your whole app runs 25% slower because you chose dynamic_cast instead of static_cast (probably less than 25%).  But there is no way the cast itself is just 25% slower for choosing dynamic instead of static.

Comment: @JSF: I wrote a benchmark to compare classic C casts with C++ casts using classes resembling the ones whose performance had been called into question by a classic C dev.  *Of course* that benchmark only shows the perf difference between *different C++ casts*, not of the app in total.  So, yes, I do have an idea what I was doing.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing.  The only person who can decide which of the alternatives is 'better', is the owner of main.  If you are, and your code only has to work for a month, say, then the trade-off is up to you.

Comment: @n.m. What's UB? Also, why would I use dynamic_cast when I know there is absolutely no chance of it to fail?

Comment: UB is undefined behaviour (you need to be familiar with the term). "I know there is absolutely no chance of it to fail" —  I think I've seen this phrase somewhere in a list of famous last words. You may know it will never fail right now. Will you know that in 3 years after 6000 commits by 17 different people?

Comment: Well, I missed the obvious fact that it is CRTP, in which case you can probably get away with static_cast. There are ways to statically ensure it will always be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) so `static_cast` is idiomatic here.

You can avoid casting in this case in numerous ways. The simplest is to change the constructor to:

```
BaseNode(const char* nodeName, T* parent, T* thisAsT);
```

and add an appropriate field:

```
//...
T* _parent;
T* _thisAsT;
```

So in `addChildNode` you will have an easy access to the `this` pointer with the appropriate type:

```
_children.push_back(new T(name, _thisAsT));
```

This of course requires your derived classes to provide a valid pointer for this argument in their constructors.

---

Another one, however a bit kludgey is to add:

```
virtual T* buildFromName(const char* name) = 0;
```

and then use it in `addChildNode`:

```
_children.push_back(buildFromName(name));
```

This however requires derived classes to implement a factory method for their own type, which violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for example. Creating a factory type for each derived class seems an overkill here on the other hand.

---

Second idea, with similar properties to the above:

```
virtual T* getThis() = 0;
```

and then:

```
_children.push_back(new T(name, getThis()));
```

---

<sub>Few side-notes:</sub>

<sub>- consider using `std::string` instead of `const char*`</sub>

<sub>- declarations should be written as `T* x` not `T *x` (also `const char* x` instead of `const char *x`) - the star is not a part of variable's name, it is a part of the type specifier, so should be on the "type side"</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll just use static_cast. About your second note: I just love this convention. It emphasizes the "pointer" property of the variable. It's also a bit more "correct" to write the star with the name since when typing something like `int* p1, p2;` p2 will actually be an int, not int*. That's just me :P

Answer (score 1):

A static_cast is correct.
dynamic_cast is much slower than you need.
reinterpret_cast is incorrect.  You do not know that the base class portion of a derived object starts in the same place as the derived object.  A static cast adjusts the address if needed.  A reinterpret_cast does not.

Comment: In percentage, how much is dynamic_cast slower than compilation time casts?

Comment: @pilpel For the cast itself, a static_cast often takes ZERO instructions and ZERO time.  A dynamic_cast is never zero time.  The percentage would be highly varied from many thousand % up to infinite.  Even if the % is infinite, we still might not be talking about a lot of time.  But I have run into situations where changing an unnecessary dynamic_cast to static (inside a loop) saved hours of total execution time.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast are still different. If the size of the base class and derived class differ, it is possible that the baseclass pointer and the derived class pointer to the same object have different addresses - if there is a virtual table.

See: [About dynamic cast and address of base and derived objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005389/about-dynamic-cast-and-address-of-base-and-derived-objects)

If there are no virtual methods, a static_cast would do -> compile time cast (faster in execution).

Comment: Even if there are virtual methods, a static_cast is fast and correct.  A dynamic cast is slower (with or without virtual methods).  When a reinterpret_cast is a tiny bit faster than a static_cast, the reinterpret_cast is necessarily wrong.  In cases where the reinterpret_cast works (though technically still incorrect) a static_cast will generate identical code to a reinterpret_cast.